Can this Casimir-effect integral be reduced to a special function?
This integral plays a central role in a physics problem (Casimir effect)${}^\ast$
$$\Omega(\phi,L)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Re}\int_0^\infty \ln\bigl[1+\beta(\omega)^2 e^{i\phi-2\omega L}\bigr]\,d\omega,$$
$$\beta(\omega)=\omega-\sqrt{1+\omega^2},\quad L>0,\quad 0<\phi<\pi.$$
I know the small-$L$ asymptotics and the large-$L$ asymptotics, but for the full $L$-dependence I must resort to a numerical evaluation. Does there exist a closed-form expression, perhaps in terms of some special function? The large-$L$ Taylor expansion${}^{\ast\ast}$ suggests a representation as a series of Bernoulli polynomials.


$^\ast$ $\Omega$ is the energy of a Josephson junction of length $L$, as a function of the superconducting phase difference $\phi$. The derivative with respect to $\phi$ gives the supercurrent through the junction, the derivative with respect to $L$ gives the Casimir force, see arXiv:2310.06672.
$^{\ast\ast}$
The Taylor series expansion of $\Omega$ for large $L$,
$$\Omega=\frac{1}{2\pi}\operatorname{Re}\biggl[(L^{-1}-L^{-2}+L^{-3}-L^{-4}+L^{-5}-L^{-6})\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{i\phi})+{}$$
$$\qquad{}+(\tfrac{1}{4}L^{-4}-L^{-5}+\tfrac{5}{2}L^{-6})\operatorname{Li}_4(-e^{i\phi})-\tfrac{9}{16}L^{-6}\operatorname{Li}_6(-e^{i\phi})+{\cal O}(L^{-7})\biggr],$$
is a polynomial in $\phi$ in view of an identity relating poly-logarithms and Bernoulli polynomials,
$$\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li}_{2n}(-e^{i\phi})=-\tfrac{1}{2}(-1)^n\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}B_{2n}\left(\frac{\phi+\pi}{2\pi}\right),\;\;0<\phi<\pi.$$
The small-$L$ expansion of $\Omega$ has terms that depend logarithmically on $L$,
$$\Omega=\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\phi/2)-\frac{1}{2\pi}(L\ln L)\cos\phi+{\cal O}(L),\;\;0<\phi<\pi.$$


Potential leads: The Casimir effect is often related to the Hurwitz zeta function, whose derivative provides the Bernoulli function, an analytic continuation of the Bernoulli polynomials $B_n(x)$ to $B_s(x)$. The Bernoulli function and its relation to polylogarithms is discussed by Milnor in "On polylogarithms, Hurwitz zeta function, and the Kubert identities". See also "Basic zeta functions and some applications in physics" by Klaus Kirsten.
